# extend/modify vim highlighting for all filetypes at once?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

How do I extend/modify vim highlighting for *all* filetypes at once?

I have certain relatively simple patterns which I'd like highlight differently, that can occur in any filetype. So rather than adding something like the below to every conceivable filetype I might use (~/.vim/syntax/python.vim, .../css.vim, .../html.vim, ...) is there some way I can define it once for all filetypes?

```
syn match   SpecialComment  "@[@\-+].*" containedin=Comment
syn match   Comment     "\* .*$"hs=s+1  containedin=SpecialComment
```

**update:**

As suggested I saved my changes to `~/.vim/after/filetype.vim`, with the result that it works in [Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/index.html) but not stock Gvim or Vim. The actual code I'm using [here](http://pastebin.com/nKxHcZkX), a sample python file to test against [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leo-editor-team/leo-editor/trunk/annotate/head%3A/leo/core/leoVersion.py), and the desired result:

[image: what the pastebin filetypes.vim looks like in Cream]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>You could try putting those two lines in `~/.vim/after/filetype.vim`.  That should get sourced after any of the top level syntax files.  It's possibly not the 'correct' place to put it, but it should work.</del>

filetype.vim seems to be sourced BEFORE the syntax files, so it gets overwritten by the default syntax file.  Therefore, I'd recommend you create a new file called something like:

```
~/.vim/after/common_syntax.vim
```

with the highlight lines that you're interested in.  Then, add this to `~/.vim/after/filetype.vim`:

```
if !exists("after_autocmds_loaded")
    let after_autocmds_loaded = 1
    au BufNewFile,BufRead * source ~/.vim/after/common_syntax.vim
endif
```

This will cause the file to be sourced once the file has been read.

P.S. Responding to the comment in your sample code: "why can't we use plain ol 'comment' group instead of 'pythoncomment' etc. ?", it's because the syntax highlight group is pythonComment, which is merely coloured in the same way as Comment.  If your syntax is unique enough for it not to be a problem, you could just do `containedin=ALL`.  If it is close, but not quite unique, you could do `containedin=ALLBUT,conflictgroup` where `conflictgroup` is the highlight group you want to steer clear of.

Comment: thanks, that does work. I do need to name each comment type in the first line (pythonComment, cssComment, etc.), still a lot less work than multiple files. :)

Comment: correction: it works with Cream-for-vim but not for gvim or vim proper (on my machine: Ubuntu 10.10, gvim 7.2.33). There must be a secondary setting needed somewhere.

Comment: many thanks Al, that indeed makes it work. It breaks in Cream, but I think that can easily be remedied by copying the same files into the cream plugins tree, and my primary target is (g)vim in any case. I especially appreciate you taking the time to address my secondary in-code question too.